# Fail to pass multiple value to PnP powershell cmdlet

Tags: pnp-powershell

I need to add a Choice column with PnP cmdlet:

```
$str = "Option A","Option B"
Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Choice -DisplayName "Field A" -InternalName "Field A" -AddToDefaultView -Choices $str
```

By using above script, the choice field is added but there is only one choice option `"Option A","Option B"` added.

If I use below script

```
Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Choice -DisplayName "Field A" -InternalName "Field A" -AddToDefaultView -Choices "Option A","Option B"
```

it works as expected. 2 options "Option A" and "Option B" are added.

How should I pass $str into Add-PnPField properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the choices as an array of strings.

`$choices = @("Red","Green","Blue")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I read the doc and it said the parameter should be string (https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPField.html). Seems doc is not accurate